# Ошибка 428 в скрипте на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, http, requests

Есть запрос в скрипте

```
session = requests.session()
session.verify = False
...

response = session.put(f'{api_url_head}/first/{first_id}/second/{second_id}', json={})
```

в ответе приходит 428 ошибка и **ETag header field was not set**
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это решается?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

428 http код значит — сервер указывает клиенту на необходимость использования в запросе заголовков условий

Также текст ошибки (header field was not set) указывает на то,что
поле заголовка не было задано

Пропишите headers

Comment: От сервера приходит json
Правильно ли я понимаю, что новый будет выглядеть 
`response = session.put(f'{api_url_head}/first/{first_id}/second/{second_id}', json={}, headers={'application/json'})`

Comment: @mesfex  это не имеет значения,сервер возращает код и тело ответа либо просто код, коды 1XX это информационные, 2XX это успешные коды(обычно это код 200), 3ХХ это коды редиректа, 4ХХ это коды ошибок со стороны клиента,5ХХ - ошибки со стороны сервера, подробнее можете прочитать тут https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_HTTP#426

Comment: @mesfex если больше не требуются никаких заголовков то да